# Compiling Problems

Tags: compiling

I just installed Texstudio on a new computer. I am trying to compile a file that compiled before. Now I am getting the error massages before. What should I do?

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "clblcohV13".tex

C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:686: C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:646:
no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil

Running the command C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\fmtutil.exe

kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt The command name is
C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\mktexfmt

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Does this happen with a test file as well, just a onliner: Here I am? Or does this only happen with your file clblcohV13? If the latter, you'd have to provide a minimal example.